# Makefile finds wrong python installation (python 2 instead of python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x, makefile

I'm trying to build Pyodide on a Mac and have hit a snag with what appears to be my default python installation. I've tried the solution [here](https://superuser.com/questions/304220/how-can-i-update-the-default-python-installation-fix-my-path-on-mac-os-x-10-6-7), but I'm still getting the following error on building using the makefile:

```
stg-MBP:pyodide stg$ make
make -C packages
../bin/pyodide buildall . ../build \
    --ldflags="-O3 -s "BINARYEN_METHOD='native-wasm'" -Werror -s 
EMULATED_FUNCTION_POINTERS=1 -s EMULATE_FUNCTION_POINTER_CASTS=1 -s 
SIDE_MODULE=1 -s WASM=1 -s "BINARYEN_TRAP_MODE='clamp'" --memory-init- 
file 0" -- 
host=/Users/stg/workspaces/pyodide/cpython/build/3.7.0/host 
--target=/Users/stg/workspaces/pyodide/cpython/installs/python-3.7.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pathlib
/usr/bin/python: No module named pyodide_build
make[1]: *** [all] Error 1
```

My .bash_profile only contains the following lines:

```
alias python=python3

# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

However, the terminal returns the following responses to these commands

```
stg-MBP:pyodide stg$ which python
/usr/bin/python
stg-MBP:pyodide stg$ python --version
Python 3.7.0
stg-MBP:pyodide stg$ python
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 26 2018, 23:26:24) 
[Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
stg-MBP:pyodide stg$ alias
alias python='python3'
```

I've tried clearing the hash table and restarting terminal, but I still can't get make to find python3 instead of python2 (I'm assuming the culprit is the fact that `which python` still returns the system python instead of python3.) Is there some way to point the makefile to the correct python3 installation at least for the current terminal session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only evaluated by login shells, and aliases are not inherited by subshells, so the alias is not active when the Pyodide build runs.

You either need to edit `bin/pyoide` in the build tree, or you can put a symbolic link to `python3` under the name `python` in a directory and add this directory to the front of `PATH`, like this:

```
PATH="/path/to/directory-with-symbolic-link:$PATH" make
```

This way, `python` will invoke the Python 3 interpreter because `PATH` is inherited by subshells.